# Proof regarding $\operatorname{arccot}$, where am I mistaken?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, trigonometry, inverse

We know that if $\cot(-\theta)=-\cot(θ)=\cot(\pi-θ)=x$, then

1. $ \cot(-θ) = x     \quad\implies\quad  -θ = \newcommand{\arccot}{\operatorname{arccot}}\arccot(x)  \quad\implies\quad     θ
       = -\arccot(x)$
2. $-\cot(θ) = x  \quad\implies\quad \cot(θ) = -x  \quad\implies\quad θ =
           \arccot(-x)$
3. $\cot(π-θ) = x \quad\implies\quad π-θ = \arccot(x)  \quad\implies\quad θ =
               π-\arccot(x)$

Now we get that $$\arccot(-x)=π-\arccot(x)=-\arccot(x)$$ because my book has  $\arccot(-x) = π-\arccot(x)$ and I added $\arccot(-x) = π-\arccot(x)=-\arccot(x)$. This leads to misleading statement $pi=0$, but my steps are not wrong (I guess). Where am I mistaken?

Comment: For every inverse trigonometric function, there is a principal value. For example, $\cot^{-1} x$ is defined as that angle $\theta$ that lies in the range $0 < \theta < \pi$ such that $\cot \theta = x$.

Comment: so where is the mistake, please help!

Comment: The identity $\operatorname {arccot} \cot x = x $ is false in general because of the definition of $\operatorname {arccot}$. The one that always holds is $\cot \operatorname {arccot} y=y $.

Comment: could you relate above expressions and explain, that would be grateful and save my time. thanks in advance -G.Sassatelli

Comment: arc cot (-x) is not equal to -arc cot(x). For example, arc cot (-1) is not $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ but equal to $\frac{3\pi}{4}$.

Comment: i got you #Muralidharan, also please tell me which step among above is invalid?

Comment: @Muralidharan $\cot (-\pi/4) = \cot (3\pi/4)$, all of this mess is happening because we take range of $\cot^{-1}$ as $[0, \pi]$, you can also take it as $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$

Comment: @Muralidharan $\cot^{-1} (-x) = -\cot^{-1} (x)$ if the range of $\cot^{-1} (x)$ is taken as $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ else not. right ?

Comment: Yes, but the usual principal range for $\cot^{-1}(x)$ is $(0, \pi)$.

Comment: @A---B, yeah but we would have to take the range as $[-\pi/2,0)\cup(0,\pi/2]$ because $\cot$ isn't defined at zero. Also, I think whoever decided to make $(0,\pi)$ the standard range wanted $\operatorname{arccot}$ to be continuous. For what it's worth, [wolfram|alpha agrees with you](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arccot(x)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few incorrect statements in your reasoning. First let's establish what has been said thoroughly in the comments. The $\cot()$ function takes any real number besides a multiple of $\pi$ as its input and can return any real number as its output. The $\newcommand{\arccot}{\operatorname{arccot}}\arccot()$ function is defined to take any real number as its input and return a number in the range $(0,\pi)$ as its output. It is necessary to restrict the range of $\arccot()$ like this because otherwise it wouldn't be a function (remember that each input needs a *unique* output). Because of this restriction, some sensible statements about $\arccot()$ can be made, that aren't actually true. For example, one of your statements above is

> $$\cot(-\theta) = x \quad\implies\quad -\theta = \arccot(x)\;.$$

This isn't true. For example $\cot(-\frac{37}{2}\pi) = 0$, but $\arccot(0) \neq -\frac{37}{2}\pi$ because $\arccot(0)$ has to be in the range $(0,\pi)$. In fact, many values make $\cot()$ return $0$, but only *one* of those values can be returned by $\arccot(0)$. You also made the statement

> $$\arccot(-x) = -\arccot(x)\;.$$

This isn't ever true. Because $\arccot()$ must always return a positive number we have $\arccot(\_) \neq -\arccot(\_)$ for any choice of inputs.

Comment: Thank you very much, finally i got what i was looking for. Thanks again for giving time to my problem.